# ZipFile c# trouble

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Ошибка - Не удается найти конец записи главного каталога.
При таком коде:

```
//где pathToGame путь до игры через FileBrowserDialog, можно даже взять произвольный
//По типу @"c:\", один хрен не работает, ошибка та же, кто знает как фиксить?

string zipPath = pathToGame + @"\test.zip";
string extractPath = pathToGame;

ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
```

Но! Перед этим этот Zip архив скачивается с интернета по ссылке из гугл диска, в функции когда он уже скачается идёт код который выше.

```
if (downloadStartedNow) return;

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pathToGame))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Сначала Вам необходимо указать путь установки!");
    return;
}

String fileName = "test.zip";
String link = ""; //любой линк на zip file из инета (ссылка должна быть прямая)

if (File.Exists(pathToGame + @"\" + fileName))
    File.Delete(pathToGame + @"\" + fileName);

WebClient client = new WebClient();

client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(link), pathToGame + @"\" + fileName);

label1.Text = "Началась загрузка дополнительных компонентов...";
downloadStartedNow = true;
```

Comment: Архив открывается архиваторами? Тестирование архиваторами проходит? Если нет, то архив либо выложен битым, либо не скачан целиком

Comment: С архивом всё впорядке, он распаковывается и открывается, а вот именно в коде он выдаёт ошибку, при попытке распаковать. Но ещё один момент, если скачанный файл не перекачивать, а просто скачать и оставить там, то распаковка пройдёт на ура, я думаю после того как файл скачался, нужно будет поставить какую-то задержку, ну или ещё что-то?

Comment: А вы дожидаетесь завершения скачивания? DownloadFileAsync только начинает качать, надо дождаться события DownloadFileCompleted и только тогда распаковывать начинать.

Comment: Да, я же написал, я распаковываю архив в функции завершения скачивания файла.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно уже неактуально, но всё-таки отвечу.
Возможно, что в папке, куда вы распаковываете архив уже есть один из таких файлов и из-за этого может выкидывать ошибку. Чтобы починить, подставьте код в try, после этого он просто будет пропускать файлы, с которыми произошла какая-либо ошибка или которые уже существуют.